# How to create grid of UIImageView dynamic using for loop?

Tags: ios, iphone, for-loop, uiimageview, logic

I want to create a dynamic grid using for loop but I can't. I create demo here but it is not work and I can't understand the logic of this because I'm new in this.

It is important that I have to use for loop no others. So please give me any solutions using for loop. This is in my viewDidLoad method.

```
int x=5;
int y=5;
int hei=50;
int wid=50;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) 
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        if (i==0 && j==0)
        {
            imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, wid, hei)];
            [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Motocross.png"]];
            [self.view addSubview:imageView1];                        
        }
        else 
        {
            imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+wid+5, y+hei+5, wid, hei)];
            [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Motocross.png"]];
            [self.view addSubview:imageView1];
        }

    }   
}
```

In that I want to create dynamic grid and the size of UIimageView is 50*50 and the space between UIImageView is 5. So in demo I generates only 3*3 grid (same as gallery in mobile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate only 3x3 grids because that is the value defined in your loop initialization, if you want a bigger grid just change those value, for instance for a 5x5 grid :

```
int x=5;
int y=5;
int hei=50;
int wid=50;

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((x+wid)*i, (y+hei)*j, wid, hei)];
        [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Motocross.png"]]
        [self.view addSubview:imageView1];

    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This code is very easy and now i understand the logic.

Answer (score 3):

please try this code it works for 2*2 grid. And change upon your requirement

```
    -(void)loadThumbScroll{

    UIButton *button;

    NSUInteger n = [arrimg count];
    int i=0,i1=0;

    while(i<n){
        int yy = 15 +i1*90;
        int j=0;

        //this is for column
        for(j=0; j< 2;j++){

            if (i>=n) break;
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(15+150*j, yy, 140, 80);
            imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: rect];];
                [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Motocross.png"]];
                    [self.view addSubview:imageView1];   

            i++;

        }
        i1 = i1+1;
    }

    [thumbScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(thumbScrollView.frame.size.width, button.frame.origin.y+button.frame.size.height+20)];

}
```